What differences in terms of fields does a grounded metal and an unconnected metal object have
I previously asked a question regarding absorption and reflections of waves to metal. But id like to know the differences that say a PCB metal pour that is connected to a signals return path, and a metal pour that is not connected to anything? Would the field between the trace and metal pour still be guided well regardless? ( In this scenario I'm assuming there is a large pour of metal connected to 0v, and a rectangular section replaced with just a plane metal peice somewhere under the top trace).
I ask this because I still struggle to understand how the ground plane on Transmissions lines helps to contain and guide the field (and not reflect the wave everywhere), yet a ground plane under a GPS antenna or a reflective antenna component is not exactly trying to guide or contain any field?) The only difference I can think of is that the latter 2 are not connected to the signals reference voltage?
